# UICollectionViewDropDelegate breaks reordering cell mechanics in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, drag-and-drop, swift4

I'm trying to implement two collectionViews with drag and drop cells between them. But i faced strange behaviour with reordering cells inside collectionView. Here is minimal code that replicate that behaviour.

Provided code works as expected but then i uncomment `collectionView.dropDelegate = self` it doesn't work anymore. I tried to find which method of `UICollectionViewDropDelegate` is called but none of them is called.

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDropDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, performDropWith coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator) {
        print("in drop")
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var items = [UIColor.red, UIColor.green, UIColor.blue]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
//        collectionView.dropDelegate = self
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.contentView.layer.backgroundColor = items[indexPath.item].cgColor
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, canMoveItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        let temp = items.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.item)
        items.insert(temp, at: destinationIndexPath.item)
    }

    @IBAction func handleLongGesture(_ gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        switch gesture.state {
        case .began:
            guard let selectedIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: gesture.location(in: self.collectionView)) else {
                break
            }
            self.collectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)
        case .changed:
            self.collectionView.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.location(in: gesture.view!))
        case .ended:
            self.collectionView.endInteractiveMovement()
        default:
            self.collectionView.cancelInteractiveMovement()
        }
    }
}
```

[example without dragDelegate](https://gifyu.com/image/ETww)

[example with dragDelegate](https://gifyu.com/image/ETwH)

So this it happens and what i should do to get normal behaviour with `dragDelegate`?

Comment: Try referring this tutorial - https://hackernoon.com/drag-it-drop-it-in-collection-table-ios-11-6bd28795b313

Comment: Thank you, i saw it. It's a solution but for complex object (i mean if cell is not simple image but a bunch of texts, images and other data) it would require addition effort while using collectionView reordering (without dragDelegate) would work out of box.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit ugly, but I had this problem and the simplest thing I could find that works is to disable the dropDelegate when your gesture recognizer is invoked.

```
@IBAction func handleLongGesture(_ gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    switch gesture.state {
    case .began:
        guard let selectedIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: gesture.location(in: self.collectionView)) else {
            break
        }
        self.collectionView.dropDelegate = nil // Drop delegate behaves VERY badly with beginInteractiveMovementForItem
        self.collectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)

    case .changed:
        self.collectionView.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.location(in: gesture.view!))
    case .ended:
        self.collectionView.endInteractiveMovement()
        self.collectionView.dropDelegate = self
    default:
        self.collectionView.cancelInteractiveMovement()
        self.collectionView.dropDelegate = self
    }
}
```